# Click with waitForEvents cause Timeout error when using Gauge and Taiko

Tags: javascript, testing, e2e-testing, getgauge, taiko

I'm using Gauge and Taiko (v1.3.2).

```
Gauge version: 1.4.3
Commit Hash: f98dd40

Plugins:
html-report (4.1.4)
js (2.4.0)
screenshot (0.1.0)
```

I have a form that have a Save button. I want click the Save button and make sure that the form is fully submitted.

So I use the following code:

```
await click('Save' , {
            waitForEvents: ['firstMeaningfulPaint'],
            navigationTimeout:40000});
```

The Gauge timeout in `js.properties` is:

```
test_timeout = 40000
```

**What actually happen:**
The Save button being clicked and the form submit. Also it navigate to the next page and wait there. The page loads and you can see the elements of the page. after some moments its return this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the next page, there could be something wich is still loading in the background and not visible on the front-page.

Workaround:

```
setConfig( { waitForNavigation: false});
```

and after the loading of the page

```
setConfig( { waitForNavigation: true});
```

Comment: Yes I checked. All the resources load in the Network tab in Chrome DevTools.

Comment: sorry then I have no idea, what the problem could be.
a work around could be: setConfig( { waitForNavigation: false});
and after it to activate again: setConfig( { waitForNavigation: true});